# How to call the controller by passing complex objects as parameters in Grails with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, grails

I have this method on my Controller:

```
def save(String formAction, MyCommand editCmd) {
```

And there is a form on my HTML (I'm using thymeleaf, grails, spring-boot, etc)
And there is the submit button to save the command to the database.
Everything is working fine.

What I need to do now is, modify the way we're calling this method so instead of a submit button I need an ajax call.
How do I do an ajax call to the save method by passing the same parameters? Is it possible to call it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you can probably do something like that:

```
 const params = $("form").serialize();

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../save",
        data: params,
        success: function (data) { .. }
 });
```

Comment: It work partially. I can call the controller and I can see the params in there, but after it executes the controller it's expecting some page back from thymeleaf. I want to just call the function from ajax on the return. I don't want to fresh the screen or display anything new.